# GET and PUT under the same transaction in spring with REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am learning spring mvc with rest with gigaspace as backend store instead of a database. I doing a basic get and put operation i.e. i send rest request to get me a object say id-1, then on the front end user makes some changes to the object and clicks save button, a put request is sent with the data and the object is updated in space.

Now if there are multiple users, i want to ensure that when user-a reads the object with id-1 and clicks the edit button a lock should be acquired in the space for this particular object and if any other user tries to access the same object they should not be able to view this object unless save action is completed where the lock should be released.

To ensure this behavior how i can i make sure that id-1 is read and saved in same transaction with REST

Comment: If I GET the object and never PUT it it will be locked forever. Also a GET request must not have side effects. You could implement a locking mechanism that requires a user to actively acquire and release a lock if necessary. But I question the necessity in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look for [eTag](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#conditional.etag), if it will help you. You can write your own optimistic locker class, or use @Version annotation for your entity to keep information about changes on entity. Just add:

```
@Version
private long version;
```

This information will be in headers.
I found [this article](http://springinpractice.com/2013/09/14/optimistic-locking-with-spring-data-rest) for optimistic locking :)